# Вывод js на сайты кэширование

Tags: javascript, кэширование

Доброго времени суток друзья. Не знаю как побороть кэширование.

код который выводит блок ссылок на сайт

```
 <span id="xlink295"></span>
    <script async src="https://x-linkpay.com/go.php?for=295"></script>
```

Код на самом сервере:

```
<!-- БЛОК ССЫЛОК -->
<?php }
if ($inf['ty'] == 2) {
$fromto = 'https://'.SITE.'/fromto/'.$id;
$adq = mysqli_query($connect_db, "SELECT * FROM t_ad WHERE site='$id' AND st = '1' AND type = '2' AND payed = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $inf[how]");
if ($inf['wh'] == 1) { $wh = ''; $dv1 = '<div style="margin: 10px 0;">'; $dv2 = '</div>'; } else { $wh = ' '; $dv1 = ' '; $dv2 = ' '; }
$toad = ''.$dv1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($adq)) {
if (!empty($row['col'])) { $col = ' style="color: #'.$row['col'].'; font-weight: bold"'; } else { $col = ''; }

$cl = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect_db,"SELECT id FROM t_sta WHERE si = '$id'"));
$toad .= '<a href="https://'.SITE.'/goto/'.$row['id'].'"'.$col.' target="_blank" title="Переходов за 24ч: '.$cl.'">'.$row['ti'].'</a><br>'.$wh;
mysqli_query($connect_db, "INSERT INTO `t_sts` (si,ad,ip,dt,ref,br,os) VALUES ('$id','$row[id]','$ip','$dt','$by','$br','$os')");
}
mysqli_query($connect_db, "INSERT INTO `t_sts` (si,ad,ip,dt,ref,br,os) VALUES ('$id','0','$ip','$dt','$by','$br','$os')");
$toad .= $dv2.'';
$ad = rawurlencode($toad); ?>
var xb = document.getElementById('xlink<?php echo $id; ?>');
xb.innerHTML = '<?php echo $toad; ?>';
<!-- КОНЕЦ БЛОК ССЫЛОК -->
```

Так вот JS выводимый кэшируется и при обновлении блока нужно сбрасывать кэш. Как побороть это ? Прошу помощи :)

Comment: Извесный "глюк". Что б скрипты обновлялись "сами" нужно добавлять что-то типа `?version=1` и увеличивать номер версии. Например `<script async src="https://x-linkpay.com/go.php?for=295&version=1` (если скрипт генится автоматически, то генератор прийдётся подправить). При каждом изменении скрипта версию нужно увеличивать. Как вариант в version можно ставить дату/md5/crc или что-то другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давай посмотрим заголовки запроса:

```
curl --head 'https://x-linkpay.com/go.php?for=295'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 13:29:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Expires: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 01:29:04 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**Expires: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 01:29:04 GMT**

Оптимальным решением задачи будет настройка ответа сервера таким образом, чтобы он явно информировал браузер о том, что ответ сервера не нужно кешировать. Например:

```
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
 Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: А где данные настройки на сервере можно воспроизвести ? С vds опыта работы не много.

Comment: @NightWos да в том же php HTTP-заголовки отпечатать, например

Comment: @NightWos почитай http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/how-to-prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не помогло. Добавил
`<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>`
В конфиг HTTPD и .htacces, все равно кэшируются результаты...

Comment: заголовок-то не изменился. нужно искать то место, которое выставляет  на 12 часов заголовок Expires. в пыхапешном кодилище, в httpd.conf, везде. ещё, может, апач рестартануть надо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036941/setup-http-expires-headers-using-php-and-apache

Comment: @norbornen Да, сделал через один htacces, все идеально работает! Спасибо огромное!